# What does 小職の権限 mean?

Tags: words, phrases

This is from a e-mail sent to me in my work place.

I tried to search in the internet for the whole phrase but there is no direct translation.

When I tried to search for the meaning word per word, I found that:
小職 - have a meaning lowly government servant, I, etc.
権限 - have a meaning power, authority and jurisdiction.

With these, I think it's a phrase that humbly pertains to oneself.

Is my deduction correct?
What is its proper English word equivalent?

Comment: It's a noun 権限 with modifier 小職. Likely used in an expression "within my responsibilities/power", but who knows...? Only you, because you don't think interpretation requires quoting the full expression.

Answer (score 7):

- {{pad}}小職【しょうしょく】 is an uncommon *humble* first-person pronoun used mainly by bureaucrats. It's simply "I" in English. Other business-related humble first-person pronouns include 本官【ほんかん】 ("I" used by police offices), 拙僧【せっそう】 ("I" used by monks), 弊職【へいしょく】 ("I" used by lawyers), etc. Don't use them to address someone.
- 権限 is simply "authority", "managing power", "right", "permission" etc.

So 小職の権限 is "my control", "the extent I have authority to", etc.

> - それは小職の権限が及ばない範囲です。 That is beyond my power/control.
> - 小職の権限で可能です。 It is possible at my discretion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The added information and warnings are also very useful. :)